# Vertical scrollable Slider inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to develop a page where i can have a vertical slide show (cointaining images and text) which changes on scrolling down and once the last slide is reached, parent page starts to scroll. You can see the example on the following page 
https://www.mi.com/in/redmi-note5/

I tried with various examples, but all of them are for full page examples. So here I would like to have the vertical slides inside a section on the page.

Hope someone can help me out here.

I am trying to use FSVS code.

You can check the attempted code here

[Trial page](http://www.creativefusion.in/Trial)

Comment: Could you show your attempt with code? It's easier to help that way

Comment: Hi Matt, I have added the page link for your reference. You can have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use slick slider.check the demos you'll get your answer.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
you can use wheel event and make sure you set `infinite: false` in slick options.

```
var $sliderElm = $('.slider');

$sliderElm.on('wheel', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        $(this).slick('slickPrev');
    } else {
        $(this).slick('slickNext');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi confusedGuy, thanks for reply, but no the slick slider also doesnt work here.

Comment: yes but you have to write custom Javascript for that. e.g on scroll you have to call its API method slick next. it's already provides you vertical slider. at least that much you can do.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Please check the demo here where i tried to incorporate slick. The problem is the slider starts to slide even before I reach to it. The moment we start scrolling, the slider also starts to  change slide. I want it to activate or initialize when the container reached the top of the page.

Comment: check my edited answer. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Hi confusedGuy, sorry to bother you again but its not working for me even now. Id it possible for you to share the working example on fiddle, so can check the same. I have updated the code as your code, but then the slider doesnt work at all. It works on dragging right or left but not on scroll.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was on a vacation. here's the demo. don't mind the images. I couldn't bother to upload anywhere. you can check it by adding content above and below the slider. it works perfectly.

https://codepen.io/neel555nc/pen/WYOWyO

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will check and let you know about its working tomorrow for sure.